# Google Compute Snapshot stuck at deleting

Tags: google-compute-engine, snapshot

Screenshot:

[image]

I have a google compute snapshot stuck at deleting. It looks like the instance was already deleted, but this snapshot has been stuck in deletion mode for days.

It's not really major, but still seems like a bug of some sort. If I try doing anything with it I get the "busy" error.

Answer (score 1):

I am quite sure if you have support package with the Cloud Platform "https://cloud.google.com/support/", you can easily open a ticket with them and submit your inquiry and they will look into it.

Or even you can post your quesion in the Google App Engine Public Issue Tracker "https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/FilingIssues?tm=3" and it will be traced and handled by the support team over there and they will tell whether it's a bug on their side or not.

In both ways, they are going to give you the best recommendations and even the workaround if found to have your issue resolved.